# AngularJS undefined when using variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

This is my first test application I have been working on using AngularJS and I seem to hitting a few errors on simple things.

I have my AngularJS service which returns JSON to my Controller (*'crucify' has been specified but this is whatever the user enters in the texbox*):

```
{"crucify":{"id":37635889,"name":"Crucify","profileIconId":984,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1450980592000}}
```

Now in my Controller I want to be able to access the JSON values '*id*' and '*name*' etc. So I have wrote this:

```
xile.controller('searchController', ['personSearch', '$scope', function (personSearch, $scope) {

$scope.search = function () {

    var summoner = $scope.summoner;

    personSearch.findPlayer(summoner).then(function (data) {
        $scope.answer = data;
    });
}

}]);
```

So data is equal to the JSON posted above. How in my HTML do I bind the '*id*' and '*name*' from the JSON? I have posted my HTML below but this does not seem to work?

```
<div>Answer: {{answer.id}}</div>
<div>Answer: {{answer.name}}</div>
```

EDIT:

The user will enter there username in a textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_searchUser" ng-model="summoner" />
```

So Crucify is an example and equals to whatever is entered in this box.

Comment: had to remove my answer since you're question is incomplete

Comment: @Leo Updated my question a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var key=Object.keys(data) //return ["crucify"], object key
$scope.summoner =data[key[0]]; //return object value
```

Comment: adding this worked. Thanks for your help :) Merry Christmas!

Comment: I'm glad to be useful. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

```js
xile.controller('searchController', ['personSearch', '$scope', function (personSearch, $scope) {

$scope.search = function () {

    var summoner = $scope.summoner;

    personSearch.findPlayer(summoner).then(function (data) {
     
      //first method
        $scope.answer = data.crucify;
      //second method
      $scope.answer = data
    });
}

}]);
```

```html
//first method
<div>Answer: {{answer.id}}</div>
<div>Answer: {{answer.name}}</div>
//second method
<div>Answer: {{answer.crucify.id}}</div>
<div>Answer: {{answer.crucify.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Please read the question. I can't specify Crucify as this is whatever the user enters in the textbox. Crucify was an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding ng-if to your divs, like this?

```
<div data-ng-if="answer.id">Answer: {{answer.id}}</div>
<div data-ng-if="answer.name">Answer: {{answer.name}}</div>
```

Comment: I've just looked at your json a bit more carefully, you have a crucify nested, have you tried using answer.crucify.id ?

edit: answer[summoner].id where summoner = 'crucify' for example